# Changing one element of an array changes others

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

I have the following piece of code:

```
Chromosome[] pop = new Chromosome[popSize];      
int[] initialGenes = new int[i];  
for (int m = 0; m < i; m++)  
     initialGenes[m] = -1;  
     for (int j = 0; j < popSize; j++)  
     {                
        pop[j] = new Chromosome(graph, initialGenes);  
     }
```

`Chromosome` is my class and has a property

```
public int[] Genes { get; set; }
```

As you can see I initialize an array of Chromosome objects. The problem is when I try to change the value of `pop[i].Genes[k]` (e.g. `pop[1].Genes[2] = 123`) all `Genes[k]` of `pop` are changed (i.e.

```
pop[0].Genes[2] == 123
pop[2].Genes[2] == 123
```

etc.)

Could anyone explain what the problem is?
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to consider having the Chromosome class instantiate the array rather than passing in an array instance.  Having multiple references to the same array instance floating around can create unexpected problems, as you've seen.  If you encapsulate the data and provide access to the Genes through GetGene and SetGene methods, the Chromosome no longer has to worry that some other code could be corrupting its state indirectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your constructor of `Chromosome` to make a copy of the array that is passed in.
I assume, your constructor looks like this:

```
public Chromosome(int[] initialGenes)
{
    Genes = initialGenes;
}
```

But it should look like this:

```
public Chromosome(int[] initialGenes)
{
    Genes = new int[initialGenes.Length];
    Array.Copy(initialGenes, Genes, Genes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you pass same object to all Chromosome clases. You should create new copy of initialGenes for each Chromosome class